# Random lines in map (bug?) with ggmap - how to get rid of them?

Tags: r, google-maps, maps, border, ggmap

I use ggmap (2.4) in R (RStudio 0.98) and I have a map of Myanmar with political borders in which I am plotting some linguistic information. Unfortunately the borders are displayed along with a few random lines in the same color that should not be there. One is straight in the north part, two others are further down in the south and extend into the ocean. I marked them with 2 red arrows.

Here's my source code:

```
library(ggmap)
burma <- get_map(location=c(lon=96, lat=20), maptype='satellite', color='color', zoom=5)
burma.map <- ggmap(burma, darken=c(.33, 'white')) + coord_map(xlim=c(92,102), ylim=c(29,10)) + borders(database="world", colour="yellow")
burma.map
```

The outcome is this: [Myanmar map with borderline syndrom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Gz8.jpg)

Looks like a bug in the vectors for the country borders.

Comment: Hallo André, Herzlich Willkommen auf StackOverflow!

Comment: Danke sehr, maj! Ich hoffe, ich mache alles richtig. ^^

Answer (score 3):

The "built-in" world map data has issues that will be cleaned up soon by the new maintainer of the `maps` package (i.e. you'll get issues even when trying to crop the polygons at times). In the interim, use other, cleaner borders and crop them so that ggplot2 doesn't have to (since it won't do a good job on it's own once `coord_map` is tossed in):

```
library(ggmap)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(ggthemes)

# get better borders

url <- "http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip"
fil <- "tm.zip"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(url, fil)
unzip(fil, exdir="tm")
world_borders <- readOGR("./tm/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp", "TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3")

# get the google map first so we know the bounding box

burma <- get_map(location=c(lon=96, lat=20), maptype='satellite', color='color', zoom=5)

# get the bounding box

bb <- as.numeric(attr(burma, "bb"))

# clip the borders to the bounding box

clip_region <- as(extent(bb[2], bb[4], bb[1], bb[3]), "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(clip_region) <- proj4string(world_borders)
clipped_borders <- fortify(crop(world_borders, clip_region))

# plot the map

burma_map <- ggmap(burma, darken=c(.33, 'white'))
burma_map <- burma_map + geom_map(data=clipped_borders, map=clipped_borders,
                                  aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                                  color="yellow", alpha=0)
burma_map <- burma_map + coord_map(xlim=c(92,102), ylim=c(29,10))
burma_map <- burma_map + theme_map()
burma_map
```

[image]

```
# alternatively use just asia read directly from GeoJSON URL
# NOTE this relies on some of the above code
# GeoJSON Asia extract made with http://geojson-maps.kyd.com.au/
# But you could use any NaturalEarth extract. This is less
# granular than the previous one

just_asia <- readOGR("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/94bdd47705d05a50f9cf/raw/0ccc6b926e1aa64448e239ac024f04e518d63954/asia.geojson",
                     "OGRGeoJSON")

clipped_borders_ja <- crop(just_asia, clip_region)
clipped_borders_ja <- fortify(clipped_borders_ja)

burma_map <- ggmap(burma, darken=c(.33, 'white'))
burma_map <- burma_map + geom_map(data=clipped_borders_ja, map=clipped_borders_ja,
                                  aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                                  color="yellow", alpha=0)
burma_map <- burma_map + coord_map(xlim=c(92,102), ylim=c(29,10))
burma_map <- burma_map + theme_map()
burma_map
```

[image]

Mercator is about the best you're going to get using `coord_map` for now. There are less "sharp" borders as well at the Thematic Mapping site. The more precise, the longer it takes to work with them.